# In Android mobile app creation, is there a way to know whether the user clicked the verification link sent during signup without using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

On clicking gmail verification link where to redirect? How to redirect to login page and know whether the user clicked the verification link or not? Any suggestions? Do we have any control over the message body that is sent to gmail?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default messages  in firebase under authentication->Template.
There are various methods.[image]

Comment: Without using firebase is there a way?I was able to send a verification link to gmail without using firbase. But i am stuck there.

Comment: yes you can use smtp to do so. Use smtp inside code and put your website credentials like admin@website.com and password in it.
follow this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: I do not still get it. The link you mentioned states how to send an email via smtp. I have successfully achieved it. I want to know on clicking the verification link we send, how do admin know whether the user has clicked the link or not in a mobile android app.

Comment: just call the method inside the button on click listener, if mail is received by the user then its obvious mail has been sent. and to check from admin side see in outbox of mail system.